# How do I start inherited uvm_test class?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to start a uvm test class with `.start()` method instead `uvm_config_db()`.

I commented out the `uvm_config_db` method and implemented `run_phase()` instead as below.

```
virtual class test_base extends uvm_test;
  ahb_agent ahb0;
  ahb_agent ahb1;

  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction

  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    ahb0 = ahb_agent::type_id::create("ahb0", this);
    ahb1 = ahb_agent::type_id::create("ahb1", this);
  endfunction
endclass

class test1 extends test_base;
  `uvm_component_utils(test1)
   main_ahb_sequence seq;
   ahb_agent agent;
  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction

  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    seq = main_ahb_sequence::type_id::create("seq", this);
  endfunction


  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.run_phase(phase);
    phase.raise_objection(this);

    seq.start(ahb0.sequencer);

    phase.drop_objection(this);
  endtask

/*
  virtual function void end_of_elaboration_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    uvm_config_db #(uvm_object_wrapper)::set(this, "ahb0.sequencer.run_phase",
      "default_sequence", main_ahb_sequence::get_type());
    uvm_config_db #(uvm_object_wrapper)::set(this, "ahb1.sequencer.run_phase",
      "default_sequence", main_ahb_sequence::get_type());
  endfunction
*/
```

After execute, I get the `NULL pointer Error`

```
xmsim: *E,TRNULLID: NULL pointer dereference.
          File: ./test1.svh, line = 42, pos = 17
```

I think this caused by `test_base` class not being constructed as well.  But, I don't know how to start the inherited test class?

I implemented this in https://www.edaplayground.com/x/JymT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error points to the handle of the sequencer: `ahb0.sequencer`.  This means the agent has not been constructed.

You need to call `super.build_phase` in the extended test class `build_phase` function:

```
class test1 extends test_base;
  `uvm_component_utils(test1)
   main_ahb_sequence seq;
   ahb_agent agent;
  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction

  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.build_phase(phase);
    seq = main_ahb_sequence::type_id::create("seq", this);
  endfunction
```

That will eliminate the `NULL pointer dereference` error.